# Seeing "Query must include a 'q' or 'query' argument" when already include a 'q'

Tags: cloudant

I have been seeing this error from Cloudant search query a few times. It is very frustrating that I cannot do much about it.
From my poor understanding that I did include a 'q' as Cloudant expected but it seems Cloudant doesn't like the 'q' I gave. hmmm... maybe who can tell me what went wrong in my request.
[image]

REST:
https://4128d68c-b866-422b-8dd9-1aa6bee2b384-bluemix.cloudant.com/nuggets/_design/view001/_search/nuggets?q=doctype%3Apost%20AND%20source_id%3A7216&include_docs=true&limit=200

CURL:
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{\"source_id\":7216}" "http://10.0.0.42:3000/api/posts/_update_cloudant"

Comment: Hey hey-- It's hard to tell exactly without seeing the full query. Could you please post that code snippet? It would also help if you provided the index definition for the view you're querying against. Thanks!

Comment: Hi brobes, I added in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed.

> method is POST which requires 'q' or 'query' in the request body.

Issue is solved after I changed my method to GET. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad you figured it out :D